# Hide standard form properties in VB.Net using an interface

Tags: vb.net, winforms, interface

In VBA you can have a Userform implement a custom interface and only the properties defined in the interface will show in the VBA Intellisense for the Userform.  I tried to duplicate this functionality in VB.Net (2010) and all the base Form properties still show.

```
Public Interface iTest
    Property TestString As String
End Interface

Public Class Form1
    Implements iTest
    Public Property TestString As String Implements iTest.TestString
        Get
            TestString = Me.txtTest.Text
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me.txtTest.Text = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

An answer to a similar question from Richard Hein is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759985/c-hiding-all-methods-of-the-usercontrol-class-from-a-derived-one), but it's for c# and a usercontrol, and I'm unable to convert it.

Comment: That's not the purpose of inheritance and it doesn't work either. You always have all properties and methods of a Form available, even if your class implements an interface, because a child class has all properties of it's parent class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cast the form instance directly to your Interface, then you will have intellisense only for the interface members.

For example:

```
Dim f1 As New Form1()
f1.ShowDialog() 'etc will show here
Dim f1AsiTest As iTest = CType(f1, iTest)
f1AsiTest.TestString = "test1" 'only member available
```

or

```
Dim f2 As iTest = New Form1()
f2.TestString = "test2" 'only member available
```

Comment: Thanks Tom.  Is there any reason not to do this, i.e., is it bad practice?

Comment: No worries! Well as far as practice is concerned, it could be useful for when passing the form about your project. For example all forms could use this interface, and rather than accepting type Form, you could accept type iTest instead. I've found inheritance with WinForms can be a bit of a pain. In our project, we use a base class for our forms and inherit. We don't need to mask Form functionality, but if you have some specifics that need "hiding" then an passing the interface only (to another method etc) is perfect for this. Rambling over!

Answer (score 2):

```
 Dim itf As iTest = New Form1()
 itf.[and here you'll only see the iTest members show up]
```

Comment: Hans, thanks for the quick response.  If I could vote both correct, I would.  I'd be interested in any thoughts on the question I asked in my comment to Tom.